# How to get/save the attachment in a slash command?

Tags: discord.py

What I'm trying to do here is get the url or raw file of a slash command attachment. Being the inexperienced person that I am, I've ran into some issues. On discord's side, it gets the option type and shows the attachment prompt. But when a user sends a command with an attachment, all I get is a string of some numbers (966169863519350854). I don't know if I'm missing something or doing it the wrong way. Below is my code and and what is printed in the console.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_choice, create_option

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)

@slash.slash(
        name="identify",
        description="Identify Image",
        guild_ids=[805487639443931136],
        options=[
            create_option(
                name="image",
                description="Attach an Image",
                required=True,
                option_type=11, #Attachment
            )
        ]
)
async def _identify(ctx:SlashContext, image):
    print(type(image))
    print(image)

client.run('')
```

Console Output:

```
<class 'str'>
966169863519350854
```

Thank you!

Comment: I recommend using a different library that supports `discord.py` and slash commands in one lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up switching over to interactions.py. Since an attachment is a class, I did `image.url` which got me the url of said attachment.